# AS3: How can I use TweenMax in a different package

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'm trying to build a separate package. In that package I would like to reference TweenMax, however I'm having trouble linking to it (error Definition com.greensock:TweenMax could not be found).

Here is my dir structure:

```
myApp
--com

----greensock
------Tweenmax etc

----myPackage
------packageClass.as
--------elements
----------elementClass.as (this is the one trying to access tweenmax)

--src
----Main.as
```

main.as is the document class, just so I can test myPackage. Doesn't do anything except instantiate myPackageClass and stick it in the displayList.

In the elementClass.as I have:
import com.greensock.TweenMax;

which flashDevelop seems to see within the ide, but when I compile I get the ...could not be found error.

So how can I reference tweenmax from my elementClass file (I have src and com dirs in the classpaths.
I'm using flashDevelop with flash player 11.7 and Flex 4.6.0 SDK.

Am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ask the hopefully obvious question, did you import the greensock folder?

```
import com.greensock.TweenMax
```

Ok let's say you did that already.  Maybe you need to tell your code where your libraries are.  Go to **File** > **ActionScript Settings**, or, on the stage's property panel, click the **wrench icon** next to the **Script** drop down menu.

You should see a dialog with three tabs, the first two of which are labeled **Source path** and **Library Path**.  Forget about the third.

In the Source path tab, you should at least have a dot - (.) - as one of the choices.  That tells flash to look for any actionscript classes it can't find at compile time in the same directory as the source FLA.  From there you can list any number of other library paths that contain supporting files.

The second tab is for SWC files.  If you have a SWC library, you can tell your FLA where to find it by pathing to it here, just as you pathed to your libraries in the Source path tab.

The images below presume that there is a folder, in the same directory as the source FLA, named **library**.  In this folder are sub folders named **src** and **swc**.  Inside src are sub folders containing the **greensock** and **facebookAPI** com folders, (the latter used here for example).  Inside the swc folder there is a SWC named exampleSWC.swc.

The paths shown in the pics below would allow the FLA to see the following imports:

```
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import com.facebook.someFacebookAPIClass;
import com.somePackageInTheSWC.someClassFromExampleSWC;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I have the import statement at the top along with src and com in the source paths.  I was using the class files, I've just swapped it out with the swc and it's finding it correctly now. But is there no way I can use the class files, I wanted them all to just sit in the com folder and play nicely with each other. The package name in greensock starts with com, so I thought it would work.